# Database fields defaulting to a certain value

Tags: php, sql, forms

I have this form that allows me to add users to my database.

When I add a new record and enter each field with data and submit, it successfully adds data to the database

However when I attempt to update that specific record and press submit my memberID field is automatically set a value and im not sure where it may be coming from (See Here https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWdDB.jpg)

I have looked all throughout my code and cant seem to find what's causing it.

Upon trying to update or delete the records after the first update, I get the following error messages: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/r94wQ.jpg)

**Add Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Insert Users</title></head>
<body>
<h2>Insert User Confirmation</h2>

<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post"/> <br> 
<?php


include('connection.php');

                    echo    "<label for='memberID' >Member ID:</label>";
                    echo    "<input type='text' name='memberID' id='memberID' />";
                    echo    "<br /><br />"; 

                    echo    "<label for='username' >Username:</label>";
                    echo    "<input type='text' name='username' id='username' />";
                    echo    "<br /><br />"; 

                    echo    "<label for='password' >Password:</label>";
                    echo    "<input type='password' name='password' id='password' />";
                    echo    "<br /><br />"; 

                    echo    "<label for='fName' >Firstname:</label>";
                    echo    "<input type='text' name='fName' id='fName' />";
                    echo    "<br /><br />"; 

                    echo    "<label for='lName' >Lastname:</label>";
                    echo    "<input type='text' name='lName' id='lName'  />";
                    echo    "<br /><br />"; 

                    echo    "<label for='address' >Address:</label>";
                    echo    "<input type='text' name='address' id='address'  />";
                    echo    "<br /><br />"; 

                    echo    "<label for='email' >Email:</label>";
                    echo    "<input type='text' name='email' id='email'  />";
                    echo    "<br /><br />";

                    echo    "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit' />";
                    echo    "<input type='reset' value='Clear' />";
                    echo    "<br /><br />"; 
 ?>
</form>
</section>

<a href="home.php">Back Home</a><br/>

<?php
if(!isset($_POST['submit'])) {  
    echo 'Please Register';
}
else {

        $memberID = $_POST['memberID'];
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $fName = $_POST['fName'];
        $lName = $_POST['lName'];
        $address = $_POST['address'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];



        $query = "INSERT INTO `members` (memberID, username, password, firstname, lastName, address, email) 
        VALUES ('$memberID', '$username', '$password', '$fName', '$lName', '$address', '$email')";
        mysqli_query($connection, $query)
        or  die(mysqli_error($connection));

        $rc = mysqli_affected_rows($connection);
        if ($rc==1)   
                    {
                    echo '<h4>The database has been updated with the following details: </h4> ';
                    echo 'MemberID: '.$memberID.'<br />';
                    echo 'Username: '.$username.'<br />';
                    echo 'Password: '.$password.'<br />';
                    echo 'First Name: '.$fName.'<br />';
                    echo 'Last Name: '.$lName.'<br />';
                    echo 'Address: '.$address.'<br />';
                    echo 'Email: '.$email.'<br />';
                    }
        else
                    {   
                    echo '<p>The data was not entered into the database this time.</p>';   
                    }
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

**View Code**

```
<?php
                require_once('connection.php');
                $query = 'select * from members order by memberID';

                include('includes/query.php');

                echo '<table>';
                echo '<tr>';
                echo '  <th>MemberID</th>
                        <th>Username </th> 
                        <th>Password</th> 
                        <th>Firstname</th> 
                        <th>Lastname</th> 
                        <th>Email</th> 
                        <th>Address</th>';  
                echo '</tr>'; 

                foreach ($rows as $row)
                {
                echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td>' . $row['memberID'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $row['username'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $row['password'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $row['firstname'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $row['lastname'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $row['email'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $row['address'] . '</td>';



                echo '<td> <a href="confirm_delete.php?memberID=' . $row['memberID'] . '">Delete</a> </td>';
                echo '<td> <a href="update_member_form.php?memberID=' . $row['memberID'] . '">Update</a> </td>';
                echo '</tr>';
                }

                echo '</table>';

    ?>
```

**Update Code**

```
<?php

    require_once('connection.php');

        if(!isset($_POST['submit']))    {

        echo "Unauthorised access";

        }
        else  { 
                $memberID = $_POST['memberID'];     
                $username = $_POST['username'];
                $password = $_POST['password'];
                $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
                $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
                $email = $_POST['email'];
                $address = $_POST['address'];


                $query = "update members set memberID = '#memberID', username = '$username', password = '$password', 
                firstname = '$firstname', lastname = '$lastname', email = '$email', address = '$address' where memberID = '$memberID'";

                $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query)                     
                    or die (mysqli_error($connection)); 

                $rc = mysqli_affected_rows($connection);

                if($rc == 1)
                {
                    echo "<p>You have successfully updated memberID: {$memberID} account details</p>";
                    echo "<p><a href='view_records.php'>Back to User List</a> </p>";
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "<p>No changes made.</p>";
                    echo "<p><a href='view_records.php'>Back to User List</a> </p>";
                }
        }

?>
```

**Delete Code**

```
<?php
    require_once('connection.php');

        $memberID = $_GET['memberID'];

        $query = "delete from members where memberID = '$memberID';";

        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query)                     
            or die (mysqli_error($connection)); 

        $rc = mysqli_affected_rows($connection);

        if($rc == 1)
        {
            echo "<p>You have successfully removed MemberID: {$memberID} from the database</p>";
            echo "<a href='list_delete_update_users.php'>Back to User List</a>";
        }
        else
        {

        echo "<p>No record deleted</p>";
        echo "<a href='view_records.php'>Back to User List</a>";
        }   
?>
```

Comment: Well, you are doing it yourself, look the typo here: `$query = "update members set memberID = '#memberID', `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this line in your update code:

```
 $query = "update members set memberID = '#memberID', username = '$username', password = '$password', 
                firstname = '$firstname', lastname = '$lastname', email = '$email', address = '$address' where memberID = '$memberID'";
```

solution:
 you got the variable via post in $memberID but while updating you are using #memberID. This might be one of your problems.

Answer (score 0):

Add and delete has nothing to do with your question, so you can leave that behind. Look at the query: "set memberID = '#memberID'". Here is your problem. Also, how is it possible that text can be inserted into the cell? I presume the column should be something like a unsigned int.

Finally, look at parameterized queries

Comment: All my table datatypes are set to varchar

Comment: @MatthewCampana Even the memberID field? Do **not** use a varchar for your primary key please.

Comment: Yes member id is set to varchar. What would be the best datatype?

Comment: Please read topics about sql data types: e.g., http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/data-types.html and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Answer (score 0):

I think its because of your update query. Check it once properly it has the following

```
$query = "update members set memberID = '#memberID', username = '$username', password = '$password', 
            firstname = '$firstname', lastname = '$lastname', email = '$email', address = '$address' where memberID = '$memberID'";
```

NOTE that you are putting **memberID = '#memberID'** - I think you should put memberID = '$memberID' there.

Comment: Thanks.. little stuff like that is so frustrating